# Auto-adjust thumbnail's position in a DIV (based on browser window width)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a website that is displaying thumbnails that fits to the side. I have a bunch of thumbnails I want to fit. How it is now, there is a big gap when a picture goes to the next line.

Is there a way to have it automatically form fit so there will always be a image on the right and space out all the other thumbnails in between?

Here's my site: [FlashPics Photostream](http://myflashpics.com/photostream)

Sorry if it was confusing. You should see if you go to the link.

Thanks,
Coulton

Comment: @k102: Please provide an example or provide a link. Thanks!

Comment: @phpnerd the link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Keoki Zee: Sorry about that, changed it in the question.

Comment: this will be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271675/jquery-screen-resolution-height-adjustment

Comment: Your site is blank to me. Before you do anything else go to the w3 html validator and fix the errors. There are a TON of errors in that HTML. So many errors that they are preventing it from rendering (in my browser anyway).

Comment: I'm using Firefox 5 and it's rendering okay for me...

Comment: @Ariel: I have tested it in Safari, Firefox, & Chrome and it loads fine for me.

Comment: @k102: Ok, what if they change the screen size?

Comment: @phpnerd211 i don't know actually. try to test it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I could not find a CSS only solution. Here is a jQuery + CSS solution instead:

## [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/9wbAk/show/) and [code](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/9wbAk/)

I've hooked a function inside the `window.resize` event that calculates the width required to show maximum number of images per row. The width is applied to the gallery wrapper so that it automatically center aligns itself within the window. The gaps between images plus the gap between left/right edge of the window remains consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a little class that take a real image and create the thumb of it maybe it can be usefull for you

```
<?php
class thumbnail
    {
        var $sourceFile; // We use this file to create the thumbnail
        var $originalFilename; // We use this to get the extension of the filename
        var $destinationDirectory; // The Directory in question
        var $destinationDirectoryFilename; // The destination filename
        var $failed ; 
        var $createImageFunction = '';
        var $outputImageFunction = '';

        function generate($sourceFile = "", $originalFilename = "", $destinationDirectory = "", $destinationDirectoryFilename = "", $width = -1, $height = -1)
        {
      if (!empty($sourceFile))
        $this->sourceFile = $sourceFile;

      if (!empty($originalFilename))
        $this->originalFilename = $originalFilename;

      if (!empty($destinationDirectory))
        $this->destinationDirectory = $destinationDirectory;

      if (!empty($destinationDirectoryFilename))
        $this->destinationDirectoryFilename = $destinationDirectoryFilename;

      if (!empty($width))
        $this->width = $width;

      if (!empty($height))
        $this->height = $height;

      list($this->extension) = explode('.', $this->originalFilename);

            switch ($this->extension)
            {
                case 'gif' :
                    $createImageFunction = 'imagecreatefromgif';
                    $outputImageFunction = 'imagegif';
                  break;

                case 'png' :
                    $createImageFunction = 'imagecreatefrompng';
                    $outputImageFunction = 'imagepng';
                  break;

                case 'bmp' :
                    $createImageFunction = 'imagecreatefromwbmp';
                    $outputImageFunction = 'imagewbmp';
                  break;

                case 'jpg': case 'jpeg':
                    $createImageFunction = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                    $outputImageFunction = 'imagejpeg';
                  break;

                default : 
                    exit("Sorry: The format '{$this->extension}' is unsuported");
                  break;
            }

            $this->img  = $createImageFunction($this->sourceFile);

            list($this->org_width, $this->org_height) = getimagesize($this->sourceFile);

            if ($this->height == -1)
            {
                $this->height = round($this->org_height * $this->width / $this->org_width);
            }

            if ($this->width == -1)
            {
                $this->width = round($this->org_width * $this->height / $this->org_height);
            }    

            $this->xoffset = 0;
            $this->yoffset = 0;

            $this->img_new = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->height); 

            if ($this->img_new)
            {
                imagecopyresampled($this->img_new, $this->img, 0, 0, $this->xoffset, $this->yoffset, $this->width, $this->height, $this->org_width, $this->org_height);

                list($this->newFilename) = explode('.', $this->destinationDirectoryFilename);

                $this->fullDestination = ($this->destinationDirectory.'/'.$this->newFilename.'.'.$this->extension);

                $outputImageFunction($this->img_new, $this->fullDestination);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->failed = true;
            }

            if ($this->failed == false)
            {
                return $this->fullDestination;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Very easy to use.

```
<?php 
require_once 'thumb.class.php' ; 
$thumb = New thumbnail;
$thumbnail->generate($tempfile,$originalname,$destination,$width,$height) ; 
?>
```