# How to center a div tag in a html page without being affected by zooming

Tags: html, css, centering

I've a html page with some div tags in it, I want to put my **container div** in center of computer screen whether I zoom-in or zoom-out.

I want to modify my html page in such a manner as [`www.bing.com`](http://www.bing.com). The homepage centers on the screen when you zoom-out, whereas, my web page continuously expands while zooming.

My HTML pagecode:

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          HTML test page
        </title>
        <style>
          .horizontal{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color: #bbb;
          }
          .vertical{
        width:100px;
        height:70%;
        background-color: #bbb;
          }
          #container{
        margin:auto;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div class="horizontal">
        </div>
        <div class="vertical" style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <div class="vertical" style="float:right;">
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal" style="float:left;" >     
        </div>
        <h1 style="font-size:3em; color:Green; text-align:center;">
             HTML Test page
        </h1>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

How to adjust my CSS code so that I can implement centralized page style same of (www.bing.com)? I want to centralize my container div on pressing `Ctrl`+`-`

Comment: do you have this live anywhere yet ?

Comment: please visit www.bing.com because this is what I need to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking that bing page you just referred us, I believe this is what you probably want this

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
            HTML test page
        </title>
        <style>
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:auto;
}
#container {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:5em;
    color:#fff;
}
#inner {
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    border:100px solid #bbb;
    color:Green;}
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div class="horizontal">
            </div>
            <div class="vertical" style="float:left;">
            </div>
            <div class="vertical" style="float:right;">
            </div>
            <div class="horizontal" style="float:left;" >     
            </div>
            <span><div id="inner">HTML Test page</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This creates a 100px sized border to your div, which is aligned in center as you want

Answer (score 1):

I just check bing.com. It seems they change position and size of their centered div using JS. It centered while page load and the same when page is re-sized. And do not forget **absolute** position for **#container**.

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
    doResize();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    doResize();
}

function doResize() {  
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#container').css('top',(windowHeight - $('#container').height())/2);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I should really appreciate for your jQuery skills, but I'd like to do that with CSS only, Anyways... THanks

Comment: If you want use only HTML + CSS, you can try make table 3x3 and put your DIV into the center cell. As far I know, there no good solution for vertical align in block layout.

Answer (score 1):

it has something to do with you using percentages rather than say Pixels or EMs

I got it so that it is staying centered but i still have it sticking to the top of the browser.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      HTML test page
    </title>
    <style>
      .horizontal{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #bbb;
      }
      .vertical{
    width:100px;
    height:250px;
    background-color: #bbb;
      }
      #container{
    margin:auto auto;
    width:750px;
    height:400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="horizontal">
    </div>
    <div class="vertical" style="float:left;">
    </div>
    <div class="vertical" style="float:right;">
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal" style="float:left;" >     
    </div>
    <h1 style="font-size:3em; color:Green; text-align:center;">
         HTML Test page
    </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit** **possibility**
you could use a MediaQuery and set the `top:###px` so that the rest of your page sets up with the center. but you would probably have to create several CSS Files or write a lot of CSS code to make it work

[Answer to css get height of screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11516371/1214743)

this answer has a link in it to media queries that takes you to  [w3.org Media Queries site](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: Thanks, But I'd like you to go to www.bing.com, because I want to center my whole div, your code is really helpful but it centered it from top side, I want my div to be in center of browser, not in top

Comment: there is a `vertical-align` in CSS but I can't for some reason get it to work on the Div inside the body tag.  you are going to have to use some form of Javascript to accomplish exactly what is going on there I think

Comment: Hmm... Okay I am searching for it.. anyways thanks for your kind help

Comment: I edited my answer. I am not sure that Media Queries will work with zooming though?  figured it was worth a shot.