# How to vertical align the div in center irrespective of screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="centered">
//Some Content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#centered
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

The above code is horizontally aligning irrespective of the screen size.
How to vertical align the same div in center?

Comment: look ath this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276572/how-to-center-a-div-tag-in-a-html-page-without-being-affected-by-zooming

Answer (score 0):

if you know the width and height of the div

then ( i have assumed it of 400 X 200), so just give negative to half values of these dimensions in margin property. you content will be centered

```
    #centered{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    }
```

**In case if your width and height are dynamic,** then `put this div in table` so that you can vertically and horizontally align this to middle

Answer (score 0):

Try below css:

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lzume)

```
#centered
{
   position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;    
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
#centered
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display: table-cell; // here is the trick
    vertical-align:middle; // and this
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5Y27/

Comment: Thanks. what if my content is like this:http://jsfiddle.net/c5Y27/3/

Comment: may be this.. http://jsfiddle.net/c5Y27/5/