# How to adapt CSS image container to different browser sizes

Tags: html, css, image, scaling

I am currently working on a website project with some friends and we've made (with the help of SO) an image container for our home page, but we'd like to adapt it to most screen sizes (like 1920x1080, 1366x768, etc. so 16:9 I guess, haven't though much about tablets and smartphones yet).

We've tried using the solution mentioned here ([Automatically resize images with browser size using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217355/automatically-resize-images-with-browser-size-using-css)) but it just scales the images really weirdly and not based on the browser, just shrinks them inside the container.

We also tried [css get height of screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516291/css-get-height-of-screen-resolution) but we got some weird results as well.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #ccc;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
}
/*Time to apply widths for accordian to work
    Width of image = 1840px
    total images = 3
    so width of hovered image = 1840px
    width of un-hovered image = 40px - you can set this to anything
    so total container width = 1840 + 40*2 = 1920px;
    default width = 1920/3 = 640px;
    */

.accordian {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*Time for some styling*/
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
/*A small hack to prevent flickering on some browsers*/

.accordian ul {
  width: 2000px;
  /*This will give ample space to the last item to move
     instead of falling down/flickering during hovers.*/
}
.accordian li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 640px;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /*Transitions to give animation effect*/
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  /*If you hover on the images now you should be able to 
     see the basic accordian*/
}
/*Reduce with of un-hovered elements*/

.accordian ul:hover li {
  width: 40px;
}
/*Lets apply hover effects now*/

/*The LI hover style should override the UL hover style*/

.accordian ul li:hover {
  width: 1840px;
}
.accordian li img {
  display: block;
}
/*Image title styles*/

.image_title {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1840px;
}
.image_title a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html5>

<head>
  <title>CdS Home</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css' />
</head>
<div class="accordian">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="image_title">
        <a href="#">Event 1</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wallpaperup.com%2Fuploads%2Fwallpapers%2F2015%2F01%2F30%2F606369%2F5510b472cf9126e305bb941e8ec8d9e8.jpg&f=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image_title">
        <a href="#">Event 2</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.betaseries.com%2Fimages%2Ffonds%2Foriginal%2F9296_1415901083.jpg&f=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image_title">
        <a href="#">Event 3</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wallpaperup.com%2Fuploads%2Fwallpapers%2F2015%2F01%2F30%2F606369%2F5510b472cf9126e305bb941e8ec8d9e8.jpg&f=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


And here is the CSS file /*Now the styles*/
```

And here is a JSFiddle link with the code running - https://jsfiddle.net/qvpy07vd/

How should we adapt the code so that it adapts to most common screen sizes? Do we have to do a different code for every different screen?

Comment: Have a look into responsive design, you want to try to make things fluid so they can scale nicely.  You can also look into media queries to hide certain things at certain breakpoints.  I currently use an adaptive approach (totally different template served to phones and tablets) , which is repsonsive between different design widths.  Basically, you need to change your absolute measurements (ie pixels) to relative ones (ie percentages)

Comment: @Pete I've seen that mentioned as well, but for some reason the answer was downvoted. I will see what I can do wth percentages :) Thank you.

Comment: correct you `html` first :)

Comment: @MoolsBytheway What do you mean? It works fine but I'm not used to HTML conventions so I don't see anything to correct.

Comment: before anything you must write valid html markup

Comment: @MoolsBytheway It is valid, since it works. I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Never Mind, my fault

Comment: would you accept javascript alternative ?

Comment: checkout my answer, good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MoolsBytheway/cdmL55Lp/) but i suggest you to try it in separate file so you can adjust screen sizes, it worked for me, Good Luck.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.accordian ul{ width:auto;} 
.accordian {    
width: auto;
overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}


.accordian li { 

    width: calc(95% / 3);
 position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 height:100%;
    border-left: 1px solid #888;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;

  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 see the basic accordian*/
}


.accordian ul:hover li{
  width:10%;
}
.accordian ul li:hover {

  width:calc( 95% - (10%*3));
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.accordian li img {
  display: block;
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
}


.image_title {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1840px;
}
.image_title a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordian">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="image_title">
        <a href="#">Event 1</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wallpaperup.com%2Fuploads%2Fwallpapers%2F2015%2F01%2F30%2F606369%2F5510b472cf9126e305bb941e8ec8d9e8.jpg&f=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image_title">
        <a href="#">Event 2</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.betaseries.com%2Fimages%2Ffonds%2Foriginal%2F9296_1415901083.jpg&f=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="image_title">
        <a href="#">Event 3</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wallpaperup.com%2Fuploads%2Fwallpapers%2F2015%2F01%2F30%2F606369%2F5510b472cf9126e305bb941e8ec8d9e8.jpg&f=1" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! We tested a few things and we used pretty much the same thing as the one you used here. It works wonders :)