# css: How to get screen height in css?

Tags: css

```html
.visitcard-ipcashier {
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 95%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

In the above code, i use height atrribute in 93%. But this varies depends on screen. How can i get screen height in css?

Comment: try to use `height:100vh;`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516291/css-get-height-of-screen-resolution

Comment: what is the difference between 100 % and 100vh? It seems to be working same

Comment: @SrividhyaS you are using fixed position so 100% is the same as 100vh because your element is positioned relatively to viewport and vh = viewport height

Comment: @TemaniAfif If i use position relative, Can I see difference between 100% and 100vh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css get height of screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516291/css-get-height-of-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't "get" the viewport height as such, in the way that you can with JS to store it in a variable, but you can use it in `calc()` to change the height of elements. For example, `height: calc( 100vh - 50px );` which would equate to "the window height less 50px".

Answer (score 7):

In this case I suggest you to use **vh** (hundreds of viewport height):
If you set `height: 100vh;` it would take 100% height of each screen.

[Code Example](https://jsfiddle.net/besartm/avhx65t8/15/)

Comment: If I use 100%, which would also take 100% of each screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript to get screen's information.

Comment: That is actually correct. Because it can't be done with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using CSS, however you can control the page design using media queries.

Or, you can get the screen height by using `screen.height` and width by using `screen.width`. [**They are JS properties**]

Here is a basic JS code of doing this:

```js
console.log("Width: "+screen.width+": Height: "+screen.height);
```