# object-fit: contain; Calculate even height based on width percentage %?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to determine if `object-fit: contain;` can work with multiple images when supplying only a width percentage. I want all `<img>`'s to be the same viewable height respective to aspect ratio and thought that giving a `max-width: 5%;` would force an implied height. I'm willing to use a `flexbox`, although when I tried using that I ended up with the same problem. In the below, the second `li` picture ("curry_2.jpg") shrinks, but not correctly.

```css
  div.imgbox {
  width: 100%
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  max-width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <ul class="imgs">
    <li><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20010806195135im_/http://rubberburner.com:80/curry_1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20010806195628im_/http://rubberburner.com:80/curry_2.jpg"></li>
    <!-- The above image, "curry_2.jpg" shrinks but not correctly -->
    <li><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20010806194159im_/http://rubberburner.com:80/all_curry1.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure why, but using `height: vw` works the way I want, by keeping the row solid. `height: vh` also works, but that allows the images to tumble on page resize thus appearing as multiple rows.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul li {
 float: left;
 height: 10vw; /* height using vW... not vH? */
}
.imgs img {
 max-height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
 <div class="imgbox">
  <ul class="imgs">
   <li><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20010806195135im_/http://rubberburner.com:80/curry_1.jpg"></li>
   <li><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20010806195628im_/http://rubberburner.com:80/curry_2.jpg"></li>
   <!-- The above image, "curry_2.jpg" shrinks -->
   <li><img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20010806194159im_/http://rubberburner.com:80/all_curry1.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using object-fit has no effect here, because it only affects the image inside the `<img>` content box, that is if we change the height/width of the box then it will have an effect.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  animation: object 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

.helper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  animation: content 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes content {
  0% {
    content: 'fill';
  }
  25% {
    content: 'cover';
  }
  50% {
    content: 'contain';
  }
  75% {
    content: 'none';
  }
  100% {
    content: 'scale-down';
  }
}

@keyframes object {
  0% {
    object-fit: fill;
  }
  25% {
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  50% {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  75% {
    object-fit: none;
  }
  100% {
    object-fit: scale-down;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="helper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x150">
</div>
```

---

Second, It's not the `vh` or `vw`, you're just assigning a height to all those `<li>` and telling the images inside them to respect it, this works only when the images are bigger than what `vh` or `vw` will evaluate too.

**say we have an image that has a height less than `10vw` we don't have the same viewable height for all the images anymore.**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.imgs img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <ul class="imgs">
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x10"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x40"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Since you want the same viewable height, then apply a fixed height the aspect ratio will be preserved since we're only applying the height, if you apply both width and height then you're basically defining a new aspect ratio.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}

.imgs img {
  /* same viewable height and a solid row*/
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
  <ul class="imgs">
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x120"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x40"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still clearly still learning. The fact that I can bind height measurements to width measurements in 1 statement seems interesting too.  I'm still not sure if I can force all images to the shortest height of all images by only stating a width in percentage.

Comment: setting the width only will cause the height to adjust just to preserve the aspect ratio, doesn't mean all images will have same height.

Comment: Right. I can use .js or just flat out define a height, but I was wondering if there was something like img::first-child(magicalElementGetHeight) then apply that to all siblings... or something. I do want them all forced down to 10% height eventually, I just can't figure out how to do that and make all the images shrink accordingly to the viewport change (the way I have that almost works, they tumble underneath of each other because 1 dimension is fixed).

Comment: No there's no such thing in CSS you can't take an element height and assign to another, you'll to include JS or use a fixed height, maybe have the fixed height defined by JS also.

Answer (score 0):

I think height `100%` doesn't mean anything since the page can have as much height as it wants. I think you mean to take the full heigh of the screen initially, for that try something like this `100vh` i.e

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    max-width: 5%;
    height: 100vh
}
ul li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Or using Javascript, set the height equivalent to some variable and then you can use percentage to reduce/adjust height accordingly

You can read more about it here

[css get height of screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516291/css-get-height-of-screen-resolution)

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed. I will think about using `vh/vw`, those seem to make sense.