# Get screen size include the source code panel/ debug panel using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).height();
$(window).width();
```

Currently I am using these two codes to get the screen size,However, if the source code panel/debug panel is on. The size of the screen will exclude, how to include the source code bar in the screen size result? Thanks.

Also, is there anyway to get the actual screen resolution of the user screen? (in case the user is not maximize the browser). Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can check this?

http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's duplicate Question please check your Question similar to this

[jQuery Screen Resolution Height Adjustment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271675/jquery-screen-resolution-height-adjustment)

See working example for your assitance
http://jsfiddle.net/9mQ2b/13/

possible with

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

Answer (score 1):

`screen.height` and `screen.width` gets the screen size, as for the debug panel, there is no way to know what size that is and exclude it from the window size etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

to get the screen resolution